# Check if any two files in a directory are identical?

Tags: unix

I'm working on OSX and I have multiple CSV files in a directory. I want to check if any two of them are identical.

I've tried:

```
cmp file1.csv file2.csv || echo "files are different"
```

This tells me that the first two files are different.

I've also tried:

```
 diff -q --from-file *.csv
```

This tells me that the *first* file is different from every other file.

But how can I check this for every file, without having to do it manually?

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me in Linux.  I do not have a Mac Terminal to test if this works there.

```
$ md5sum * | sort | uniq --check-chars=32 --group
36da49e13da596245e85e9e47ab8a04f *y

8c3c2e6aa3be26d9f1bbbcd9a401e88e *x
8c3c2e6aa3be26d9f1bbbcd9a401e88e *z
```

The program `uniq` requires sorted input.  Check its man page for other output options.

Comment: What version of `uniq` are you using?  I cannot find one that has the `--group` option.

Comment: uniq (GNU coreutils) 8.23

Comment: The most recent I've seen in production is `v8.21`. However that is not a big deal since the `-d` option does almost the same thing

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steven's answer, you should enter this into the terminal:

```
shasum * | sort | uniq
```

And that should provide you the results.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a nice shell script. A brain dead shell script would be:

```
for i in `ls`; do diff -sq --from-file=$i `ls` 2> /dev/null; done | grep identical
```

The problem with this is, of course, that it checks each file against every other file, including itself, even if the check has already been made. I'm sure there is a nice awk script that will do the right thing in even less space but I am not feeling very awk-ish right now.

Other options to diff that you might like to consider are -w if white space is of no consequence, -b if the presence of white space is important but you really don't care how much or what kind is there, --strip-trailing-cr if some of the files were made on a system that thinks it needs both a new line and a carriage return.